# I need explanation for the output of given snippet

Tags: c++, computer-science

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define CUBE(X)  (X*X*X)

int main(void) 
{
    int a = 2;
    int result = 0;
    result = CUBE(++a) / (++a);
    printf("\na=%d\nresult=%d", a, result);
    return 0;
}
```

I understand how the value of  variable **a** comes out to 6 but i could not understand how the value of variable **result** comes out to be 13.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will replace the word CUBE with (X * X * X). Therefore, the code will turn into

```
result = (++a * ++a * ++a) / (++a);
//you might think result = (3 * 4 * 5) / 6;
```

It looks like the result should be 10, but the pre-increment is applied before multiplication. So it is evaluated like

```
result = (((++a) * (++a)) * ++a) / (++a);
//a is incremented to 3 and then four, before the first multiplication

result = ((4 * 4) * 5) / 6;
```

result = 13.3333